# Prevent JavaScript event which is bound to an object to be overridden

Tags: javascript, dom-events, cross-browser

I do:

```
// Can be edited
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    console.log("A")
}
```

And then:

```
// Cannot be edited (for example, this code appears in 3rd party library)
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    console.log("B")
}
```

Then I refresh a page and see "B" in console log. Expected. But I want to prevent the second bind to actually happen. Basically, I want to lock an event and prevent it from being overridden forever (during page life). As a result, I want to see "A" in console log on page refresh.

**Note 1**: I cannot edit a part of the code with `console.log("B")` as it may appear in third party JS library.

**Note 2**: Cross-browser solution needed.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "HI!"; };

Object.defineProperty(window, 'onbeforeunload', {
  writable: false
});

window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "BYE!"; };
```

Comment: I only tried this in Chrome. I wonder if it works in other browsers :)

Comment: Doesn't work in safari: "TypeError: Attempting to change access mechanism for an unconfigurable property." Firefox detects something, but it doesn't work in firefox.

Comment: I suspected that it wouldn't be compatible :)

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to seal `window` properties like you're asking.

However, if you change your code to use `window.addEventListener()` then you can stop the event from propagating to other event listeners:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    console.log('A')
});

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    console.log('B')
});
```

`A` will be printed to the console on `unload`.

http://jsfiddle.net/voqb78hp/4/